# Spring data select top 100

Tags: java, spring-data

How can I select the top 100 through Spring data CrudRepository?
I want to do something like that by I get an error.

```
List<Person> findTop100();
```

I do not want to use queries, hibernate or anything else. I just want to do it through spring data the easy and fast way

Comment: What is the criteria for "top"?  Date entered?  Highest IQ?  Tallest?  Not clear.

Comment: No criteria, instead of findAll() that will return, say, 1500 results, I want the top 100

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a postfix "**By**" but without criteria there would works.

```
List<Person> findTop100By();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
List<Person> findAllByOrderedBy{Abc}Desc
```

**Where Abc is parameter on which sorting to be done.**

Comment: If I do not want any parameter or sorting?

Comment: you must mention a parameter on which basis you want Top 100.

Comment: I have a Date date field in my entity and this findTop100ByOrderedByDateDesc() does not work

Comment: @Query("SELECT TOP 100 a FROM Person a WHERE a.Date<='?100' ORDER BY a.Date DESC")
List<Person> findByTop(Date Date);

Comment: Maybe the reason why it didn't work for me is because I use the spring data implementation for redis